# std map constructing strict weak order and finding lower bound

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have some kind of real life walls which are characterized by two heights (leftmost and rightmost height).

e.g.

```
I        I     I  I
I     I  I     I  I
I     I  I     I  I    I
I_____I  I_____I  I____I
```

the first one has leftmost height `hl=4`, rightmost height `hr=3`, the second `hl=4` and `hr=4` and so on.

Given `hl` and `hr` my task is now to find the wall loosing minimal volume in order to reach `hl` and `hr`. So (a) only lowering the heights on either side of the wall is allowed but not increasing and (b) the lost volume should be minimal.

In a first approach I've reduced the problem to one height using the minimal height `hMin=std::min(hl,hr)`. By doing so I can fill a map with the "walls" and use `hMin` as keys and in return get the solution using `lower_bound` searching with `max(hl,hr)`.

Now considering the two heights optimal solution I'm getting into all sorts of trouble constructing a strict weak order. What I have tried until now is to extend the key for a 2nd height, use a custom less and use equivivalently lower_bound.
My custom less looks somewhat like:

```cpp
    struct KeyLess
    {
        bool operator(Key const&x, Key const&y) const
        {
            if ((x.hl + roundOff < y.hl ) && (x.hr+ roundOff < y.hr))
                return true;
            if ((y.hl + roundOff < x.hl ) && (y.hr+ roundOff < x.hr))
                return false;
            return false;
        }
    };
```

but obviously has problems for `x.hl> y.hl` and `x.hr < y.hr` or visually for these types

```
I              I  
I              I  I    I
I     I  I     I  I    I
I_____I  I_____I  I____I
```

and does not give a strict weak ordering afaik.

I would appreciate any help constructing a less operator for my problem or showing me another way of finding a solution to this problem.

---

Example

```
I              I       I  I        I     I
I              I  I    I  I     I  I     I
I              I  I    I  I     I  I     I
I     I        I  I    I  I     I  I     I
I_____I  I_____I  I____I  I_____I  I_____I
```

Given `hl=3` and `hr=5` it should return the 3rd (`hl=4` and `hr=5`).
The order the walls are saved in the map is not per se relevant as long as I can get to the solution (But I think that is also my problem to find a meaningful ordering here).

Comment: Unrelated: That `operator<` effectively does: `return ((x.hl + roundOff < y.hl ) && (x.hr+ roundOff < y.hr));` so you could replace the body of the function with that. Can you give some examples and in what order you'd like the result to be sorted?

Comment: I don't understand your problem description. But it sounds like a combinatorial problem, not a sorting problem (i.e. can't be solved simply by sorting).

Comment: Please have a look at the updated question (including the example). Thanks

Comment: What you have is a partial order, not a total order.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, why not use unordered_set or std::tie?

Comment: @RaymondChen So should I use something like a map in a map?

Comment: @KennyOstrom The particular order should not matter that much, but I was willing to have some order such that I can use some "efficient" existing algorithms like lower_bound to get the result for minimal loss wall.

Comment: If you want them to have an arbitrary order which has its own meaning, I would recommend vector. Let algorithms move things to the correct spot. If you sort them, then you're just sorting them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
struct KeyLess
{
    bool operator(Key const&x, Key const&y) const
    {
        return std::pair(std::abs(x.hl - x.hr), std::min(x.hl, x.hr)) 
             < std::pair(std::abs(y.hl - y.hr), std::min(y.hl, y.hr));
    }
};
```

I.e. ordering first by the difference in heights, then by the smaller height. If you still need to distinguish

```
      I  I        
      I  I        
I     I  I     I  
I_____I  I_____I
```

Then you can extend that by arbitrarily choosing the first as less than the second

```
struct KeyLess
{
    bool operator(Key const&x, Key const&y) const
    {
        return std::tuple(std::abs(x.hl - x.hr), std::min(x.hl, x.hr), x.hl < x.hr) 
             < std::tuple(std::abs(y.hl - y.hr), std::min(y.hl, y.hr), y.hl < y.hr);
    }
};
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this does not give the minimal loss wall by using lower_bound (or does it?). How would I then find the minimal loss wall using this ordering?

Comment: @ezegoing Is "minimal loss" `std::abs(x.hl - x.hr)`? Switching the order of the elements prioritises that. I'm not sure why it's not the 5th element in your example however

Comment: The loss in my case can be simplified to `y.hl-x.hl + y.hr-x.hr` aussuming that `y.hl >= x.hl` and `y.hr >= x.hr`

Answer (score 0):

You have a map (or set) which requires strict weak ordering, but you don't care about the order.

You can simply use unordered_map (or unordered_set) and not have to worry about it.

Or you can create a strict weak ordering. Fortunately this is already available in the standard library using std::tie from #include <tuple>

```
bool Key::operator<(const Key &rhs) const {
    return std::tie(hl, hr) < std::tie(rhs.hl, rhs.hr);
}
```

But of course, if the order actually DOES matter, but has its own meaning and can be arbitrarily changed, then you should use std::vector. Let the algorithm put things where they need to be.

Comment: I'm confused about how you're declaring the class, or why you say KeyLess. If you don't want keys, use a set.

Comment: Ok sry for the confusion. If you think of the problem with only one height it obviously makes sense to use some sort of sorting (e.g. with map and asc. ) i.o. to get the solution easily and efficiently with lower_bound. That said the order does not really matter too much for me, but the result which I can get easily by ordering somehow. That was my thinking when I was extending this to two heights.

Comment: If a comparison operator is going to give you the final output, this is going to need definitive rules and your code, along with a failing input, actual and expected output. And it's going to have to do more than just be a strict weak ordering -- it has to be the actual solution algorithm (which may or may not be possible by just a sorting rule).